# Automatically evaluate an entered value, assign a taxomomy term to the field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

We have a user entry field "Budget" which would ultimately be displayed as a range in the published page. We would like to allow the user to enter an exact value (probably rounded to nearest 100), rather than having to choose a range – but have that value trigger the assignment of a taxonomy term to display the range. So it needs to be evaluated as greater than, less than. Any suggestions on how this could be accomplished without custom coding?

Comment: this entry field is it in a content type? did you look at the Rules module?

Comment: It is one of several types of entry fields in a new content type. In Rules I don't see a way to do a more than/less than evaluation. I don't know Rules well, but so far I don't see how it could assign a taxonomy term so it would become the output display for this field, rather than being applied to the entire node. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: Hi Charles, im not so sure what would be best way, without coding it yourself, but def. check out https://drupal.org/project/rb & https://drupal.org/files/tiny-book-of-rules.pdf